# AlpineJS get model values in an external js file

Tags: model, getter, alpine.js

Having a search form I would like to get `x-model` values programatically.

I have couple of fields like:

```
<input name="member_type" type="radio" value="specialists" x-model.search="expertType">
<input name="member_type" type="radio" value="all" checked="checked" x-model.search="expertType">
<select name="association" x-model="association"></select>
```

on form submit I want to aggregate this values and build a query url for an api.

Is there a better way to go in this case, like using some other approach instead `x-model`?

How to proceed?

Comment: Using `x-model` directive is the official way to bind form input data to Alpine.js variables. You can also group the search input fields into an object if you wish.

Comment: Hi @Dauros thanks again for your feedback, right I'm checking the model values: for example `const specs = this.specs ? this.specs.value : null`, is there a more better approach?

Comment: Is there any reason you have to set an empty field to `null`? Depending on your API, you may only have to provide an object with the query parameters. So I would create a list of query keys you want to include in the query, loop over them to check which is not empty, then provide this filtered object with the query keys and their values to the API calling method.

Comment: Hi @Dauros, the API server is a Laravel instance which is using Spatie query builder to intercept the calls. The client is in Wordpress which builds with Alpine the requests before calling the API. After each request I would like to maintain in the url the call if is called directly

Comment: using spatie if filter is empty like `&filter[association.id]=` would produce wrong query

Comment: You can also use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API to build the query string, just filter out the unset/empty values beforehand.

Comment: Hi @Dauros, yes thats how I've done